# WindowsPhone 8 and AngularJs - ng-src not working?

Tags: image, angularjs, cordova

Im trying to run my (Phonegap / Angular) App on a Windows Phone Emulator.
Everything works fine but some images are not be displayed. I figured out that ng-src is the troublemaker. When im using src instead of ng-src for local images in the same folder - it works fine.

Here some examples:

dispalyed:

```
<img ng-click="mediaPlay()" ng-hide=showButton() src="img/go.png" style="float: right">
```

not displayed:

```
<img ng-src="img/{{poi.poiimage}}" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto">
```

My App works perfect on Android and IOs.

Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT*

Ok now its getting weird o0... I've putted this "img/{{poi.poiimage}}" in a p tag and it gives me this path: img/poi-12-galgentor-01.png

So i tried it with src:

```
<img  src="img/12-galgentor-01.png" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto">
```

And ng-src:

```
<img  ng-src="img/12-galgentor-01.png" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto">
```

Both worked for me!

But this...

```
<img ng-src="img/{{poi.poiimage}}" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto">
<img src="img/{{poi.poiimage}}" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto">
```

does not work.

Edit2*

Tested in the emulators browser ... works fine too. -.-

Comment: well, can you find the value of `poi.poiimage` ? something like console.log?

Comment: Have you tried `src="img/{{poi.poiimage}}"` (if it works, its a bit weird, and this shouldn't be done, but just to test.)

Comment: src="img/{{poi.poiimage}} does not work.
And the values of poi.poiimage are correct

Comment: It works fine in IE11 !? And im not getting any errors in the emulators debug-output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> this is not a solution per se: Angularjs is broken on WP8 devices.

no it is not...

i got it:

It is just a Problem with old IE's and Windows Phones.
SrcUrls have to be whitelistet. Otherwhise angular generates a "unsafe:" prefix on every src Url. 
It can be fixed by changing the angular apps config like below:

```
schreibwerkApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$compileProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {
        $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist('img/');

        $routeProvider.
            when('/splash', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/splash.html'
            }).
            when('/terms', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/terms.html'
            }).
            when('/intro', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/intro.html'
            }).
            when('/poi/:stationID', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/poi.html',
                controller: 'PoiCtrl'
            }).
            when('/directive', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/directive.html'
            }).
            when('/imgview/:stationID/:imgID', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/imgview.html',
                controller: 'ImgCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/splash'
            });
}]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Windows Phone uses a different internal url prefix: "x-wmapp". I have seen it use "x-wmapp0" so to be safe I modified the standard imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist as follows:

```
$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|chrome-extension|x-wmapp.?):|data:image\//);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not a solution per se: Angularjs is broken on WP8 devices.

A colleague of mine is working on a fix. I've pinged him and will post more info when I have it.

-- edit --
here is an issue on the Angular.js board which seems to indicate that the problems with angular on wp8 have been resolved in CDV 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I am making a Windows Universal App with Cordova and AngularJS. I tried all the solutions above and others that I found in internet, but nothing worked...

Then, I found that in my Windows 10 (pc) the `img src attributes` were appended with `ms-appx`. So, I added `ms-appx` with other options in `imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist` and it is now working...

**So, my code looks like, this,**

```
$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|ms-appx|chrome-extension|x-wmapp.?):|data:image\//);
```

I will update this answer after I test my app in Windows Phone 8.1 and Android.